# Get all the exceptions from one try catch block

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I wonder if it's posible to get all the exceptions throwed.

```
public function test()
    {
        $arrayExceptions = array();

        try {
            throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
            throw new Exception('This will never get throwed');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $arrayExceptions[] = $e;
        }

    }
```

I have a huge try catch block but i want to know all the errors, not only the first throwed. Is this possible with maybe more than one try or something like that or i am doing it wrong?

Thank you

Comment: This is not how exceptions work. If it is not something _exceptional_, you should not use Exceptions - rather create objects with details of the errors, aggregate them, and if necessary, throw an exception at the end.

(Some nitpicking: you always get all the exceptions thrown - the first one interrupts execution of the block in question, the rest is not executed...)

Comment: The whole point of `throw`ing an exception is that it terminates execution at that point and basically does a GOTO the catch block. So if you have more than one exception possible only the first will be reported. Once in the catch block execution continues with the code in the catch block and if you dont kill the program there it cnntinues after the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote it yourself: *"This will never get throwed"* [sic].

Because the exception will never get thrown, you cannot catch it. There only is one exception because after one exception is thrown, the whole block is abandoned and no further code in it is executed. Hence no second exception.

Comment: It looks like i was having a wrong idea about exceptions. I have a constructor that initialize like 70 fields, i just wanted to retrieve all posible errors throwing exceptions. So, i'm gonna change it to instead of throw a exception, save the error message, and, in the end, if there are any error throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this was what the OP was actually asking for. If the function is not atomic and allows for some level of fault tolerance, then you can know all the errors that occurred afterwards instead of `die()`ing if you do something like this:

```
public function test()
{
    $arrayExceptions = array();

    try {
        //action 1 throws an exception, as simulated below
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        //handle action 1 's error using a default or fallback value
        $arrayExceptions[] = $e;
    }

    try {
         //action 2 throws another exception, as simulated below
        throw new Exception('Value is not 42!');
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        //handle action 2 's error using a default or fallback value
        $arrayExceptions[] = $e;
    }

    echo 'Task ended. Errors: '; // all the occurred exceptions are in the array
    (count($arrayExceptions)!=0) ? print_r($arrayExceptions) : echo 'no error.';

}
```